# Hashbang + _escaped_fragment_ + ui-router without taking SEO in account

Tags: facebook, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Since my website uses non-html5 mode (#!) angular ui-router, I want it to only be able to reach the proper hashbang route, I'm not worried about crawlability. I've read that a page with `http://example.com/#!/plans-selector-selector2-selectoretc` when shared on facebook, will be fetched with `http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/plans-selector-selector2-selectoretc`, how can I make it hashbang back? 
I'm just worried about sharing on Facebook. So when a person shares a hashbang link on facebook, does it point to the hashbang page or the _escaped_fragment page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **_escaped_fragment_** will only be used by crawlers and other indexers.
Even google will index your page using **_escaped_fragment_**, but search results will always have the URL with **#!** and I think it would be same with Facebook.
When sharing your URLs make sure you are using **#!**

Comment: I have found this to not be the case with Facebook. Google does the correct thing and crawls using _escaped_fragment, but links users using #!. However, with facebook when I've provided them #! URLs as a share ref they then wind up linking from their site back to mine using the _escaped_fragment_.